# Importing a hyper-v exported image

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v

My google-fu is failing me. Badly.

One of my clients sent me a Hyper-V exported VM which constitutes a bunch of VHDs and an XML file (which I assume is the machine definition file).

Try as I might, I can't figure out how to import this machine or convert it into a format compatible with any of VMWare Workstation, Virtual Box or even Windows Virtual PC. Googling and searching the fora for a few hours has not yielded any satisfying answers.

Can anyone direct me as to how to properly import said Hyper-V exported VM into any of VMWare Workstation, Virtual Box or Windows Virtual PC please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it was indeed exported, and is not a copy/paste of the vhd and xml, then I believe you can only properly import it using Hyper-V manager.

Have you tried creating a new virtual machine, and selecting the .vhd instead of creating a new hard disk? Also, if that machine had snapshots, and was indeed exported, by pointing to the .vhd and not the .avhd you will not be in the latest state of the machine.

Comment: Y'know, sometimes I'd like to kick myself for not trying the obvious.  I blame overwork.  Thanks, simply creating a new machine and attaching the drives worked perfectly in VMWare.

Comment: How is it that a VMware VM can use a Hyper-V VHD?

Comment: @joeqwerty unfortunately, it wasn't as straightforward as that (wisht!) but not insane either; I had to create a new VM and attach the disks.  In my case I had to convert the disks from VHD to VMDK format using [WinImage](http://www.winimage.com/), then attach them to the VM IN THE RIGHT ORDER, then after booting installing VMWare Tools.  This was a bit time consuming because of the size of the disks (a magnitude of 4 hours nearly for 150GB - YMMV)